# Is this behavior expected or is it some kind of logical flaw?

Tags: actionscript-3, setter, getter

I got this private variable, let say, _var:int, and it has a setter and getter. So far so good.

The var has an initial value of 500.

When I do a var -= 5; instead of subtracting 5 from the var, it subtracts 505, I placed a breakpoint in the getter, and indeed is going there.

So, is my understanding of setters and getters poor, or this behavior is not a logical one?

Thanks.

Comment: show your code please. you're not calling a variable "var" are you?

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume that you were just using ***var*** as quick examples for your question as ***var*** is a restricted keyword.

Below is an example of how one can use setters & getters in ActionScript.

```
var bar:Bar = new Bar();
trace(bar.foo); //500
bar.foo -= 5;
trace(bar.foo); //495


package
{   
    //Class
    public class Bar
    {
        //Variables
        private var _foo:int;

        //Constructor
        public function Bar()
        {
            _foo = 500;
        }

        //Set Foo
        public function set foo(value:int):void
        {
            _foo = value;
        }

        //Get Foo
        public function get foo():int
        {
            return _foo;
        }
    }
}
```

You could also avoid using the ***set*** and ***get*** keywords by changing the function signatures to ***setFoo(value:int):void*** and ***getFoo():int***.  Some developers prefer this approach because it's more obvious that explicitly calling a function suggests additional programmation while traditional ActionScript setters and getters do not.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly my code. Now, when I do a bar -= 5; and then I chedk the value of _bar, it says: -5 instead of 495.

Comment: In my example `bar` is an instance of the class `Bar`, which is an object containing a property called `foo`.  You must change the value of `foo`, not `bar`.  please edit your question to include your code.